# Store element in array using for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino

I am trying to output the sequence `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` in an array.

I have tried to build the code below, but there is no output.

When I print `sequence`, it gives me error only with no explanation.  What is the Arduino code to print an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,]` using for loop?

```c
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      jaja();
      delay(100000);
    }
     
    int sequence[8];
    int jaja(){
      for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){
        sequence[i] = i+1;    //code to store 1 to 8 in arduino
      };
      Serial.println(sequence);
    }
```

Thank you and have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Please always include the error, since that is the explanation. It doesn’t know how to print an array since it doesn’t know what size the elements are or how many there are or how you want to print them. You need to print them out one by one how you want.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, hi sir, but how to put them into array?

Comment: They already are in an array. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Object Serial don't know print arrays. You must print array elements

```
for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){
    Serial.println(sequence[i]);
};
```